# Reccursive include from database Entity Framework .net C#

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I am new to working with Entity framework, and cannot seem to find any information solving this; or if it is even possible. I am writing code first and trying to get an object from the db.

My structure is that it is possible to make a mainThing. Each mainThing can contain multiple thing1s, with multiple thing2s. However each thing1 can also contain a new thing1 and so on.

Now to the issue, when I am getting this mainThing from the db, I do not know how many levels of thing1s to go into.

My query is like this:

````
  var copy = _db.Mainthing
    .Include(x=>x.thing1).ThenInclude(x => x.thing1).ThenInclude(x =>x.thing1).XXX.ThenInclude(x =>x.thing2)
                .AsSplitQuery()
                .AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == memainthingId);```
````

where the XXX is is where I do not know how many levels to go down, bc there is no way of knowing how many levels of thing1s there are. Is there a way to find out how many levels it is possible to go down/dynamically get them?

Comment: `Include` isn't a JOIN, or a way to write a recursive CTE. It's only meant to tell EF to eagerly load related objects. All those nested objects are still available for lazy loading. If you load all the related objects EF will fix up the relations automagically, eg if you loaded all `MainThing` entities with `MainThing.Include(x=>x.Thing1)` you'd end up with properly nested objects

Comment: If you want to load hierarchical data you *need* a recursive CTE in SQL. This can only be done with raw SQL and `FromSqlRaw`. You can build the rest of your query on top of that query